# using cronic to reduce email notifications in a wrapper script for successful backups

Tags: shell, cron

I've been using [cronic](https://habilis.net/cronic/) to silence emails from cron jobs when the job is successful. I'm trying to customize it so when a response code is 0 and the error output matches a string of "`mount: /VessRAID/RH: /dev/sde1 already mounted on /VessRAID/RH.`", to not send an email. Below is the script, then the contents of the email then my attempt at trying to suppress the email which is not working. Any idea what I may be doing wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash
# Cronic v3 - cron job report wrapper
# Copyright 2007-2016 Chuck Houpt. No rights reserved, whatsoever.
# Public Domain CC0: http://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/

set -eu

TMP=$(mktemp -d)
OUT=$TMP/cronic.out
ERR=$TMP/cronic.err
TRACE=$TMP/cronic.trace

set +e
"$@" >$OUT 2>$TRACE
RESULT=$?
set -e

PATTERN="^${PS4:0:1}\\+${PS4:1}"
if grep -aq "$PATTERN" $TRACE
then
    ! grep -av "$PATTERN" $TRACE > $ERR
else
    ERR=$TRACE
fi

if [ $RESULT -ne 0 -o -s "$ERR" ]
    then
    echo "Cronic detected failure or error output for the command:"
    echo "$@"
    echo
    echo "RESULT CODE: $RESULT"
    echo
    echo "ERROR OUTPUT:"
    cat "$ERR"
    echo
    echo "STANDARD OUTPUT:"
    cat "$OUT"
    if [ $TRACE != $ERR ]
    then
        echo
        echo "TRACE-ERROR OUTPUT:"
        cat "$TRACE"
    fi
fi

rm -rf "$TMP"
```

Here is what the email notification looks like:

```
 Cronic detected failure or error output for the command:
    /usr/local/sbin/reg-backup-cronic.sh daily

    RESULT CODE: 0

    ERROR OUTPUT:
    mount: /VessRAID/RH: /dev/sde1 already mounted on /VessRAID/RH.

    STANDARD OUTPUT:
    /dev/sde1 on /VessRAID/RH type ext4 (rw,relatime)
```

Here is my attempt at a wrapper script:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/local/sbin/reg-backup.sh $1
CODE=$?
err=$TRACE
if [[ $CODE -eq 0 && $err = "mount: /VessRAID/RH: /dev/sde1 already mounted on /VessRAID/RH." ]]
then
  exit $CODE
fi
```

Alas the emails continue.

Answer (score 0):

Hat tip to the creator of [cronic](https://habilis.net/cronic/), Chuck Houpt, for cluing me in to an answer, which was to look at the original script and why the error is happening. Case-sensitivity got the best of me:

```
if mount | grep Vessraid; then
     echo starting $1 backup >> /var/log/vessraid.log
```

Notice the case in VessRAID should have been:

```
if mount | grep VessRAID; then
     echo starting $1 backup >> /var/log/vessraid.log
```

Now emails only happen when there really is an error.